# Naming after someone with added names

Tags: names, family-members, choleh-sick

If someone R'L is sick at some point in their life and a name such as Refael is added should that name be included as well if one is naming their child after that person?

**Additional Question:** Instead of asking this as a new question I would like to add it to this question. I would ask it the other way. I have heard that when a name was added to someone who was sick then people named after this person only take the name that was added and not the entire name together. Is there any makor for this?

Comment: +1 Authoritative answers I don't have, but my sister and my cousin are both named after people who had added names, and both of them were named with those additions.

Comment: If you keep passing on the added names, then they add up because the young get old and some will get sick.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's a finite chain though, since there's only so many names that you can add. I.e., if someone's name is already Alter Raphael Chaim Menachem Shmuel et. al., what are you going to add ;)

Comment: @hod you don't _have_ to use that kind of name.

Comment: @DoubleAA True, but the chain would still be finite, there are only so many names. Also, not every ancestor gets a child named after them, so its reasonable to think the chain would be broken at some point.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yechezkel ;)

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56800/if-your-parent-changes-their-name-does-your-name-change-too

Comment: In my family, second names -- even second names given by the parents -- were usually not preserved by someone named "for" that person. However, I have no idea if my family knew what they were doing

Answer (score 1):

It seems that many poskim would hold that once a name is changed halachically (for illness or another reason) that name would now be considered the person's true name. Therefore, someone who is naming after one who's name was changed would include the added/changed name when naming the child. Additionally, there are people who have the custom not to name children after someone who died young (or was greatly afflicted) so they would often change the child's name to be different than the ancestor's name in order to avoid having the same name. Here, I would humbly suggest that they can just name the child the original name of the deceased that way they are both, naming after the deceased, and not using their (true and changed) name in the process.

Source: Sharei Halacha U'minhag - volume five, page 243 and see Even Ha'ezer 129:18