# If your parent changes their name, does your name change too?

Tags: halacha, names, children-parenting

Imagine your parent [changes his or her (Hebrew) name](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36055/changing-ones-hebrew-name?rq=1)--either by converting to Judaism and getting a name, by taking on a second name, or simply changing his/her name for whatever reason. (Not sure that the latter is often done...)

In this case, does your Hebrew name also change? Do you need to go through the [procedure](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47416/process-by-which-one-changes-their-name) for reifying a name change?

That is:

(1) If you were Ploiny ben Yitzchak and your father becomes Yitzchak Chaim, do you become Ploiny ben Yitzchak Chaim... at all? automatically? after [officializing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47416/process-by-which-one-changes-their-name) it?

(2) If you were Ploiny ben Patrick and your father becomes Pinchas Reuven, do you become Ploiny ben Pinchas Reuven...at all? automatically? after [officializing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47416/process-by-which-one-changes-their-name) it?

~~~
BONUS: What if your mother changes her name? Does your name for prayer also change?

Comment: If a parent converts to Judaism then you are not (halachically) related.  If you are Jewish (because of your mother) then you would probably not change your name. The reason for a name change of a Jew, would be if your father is sick and gets a name added (usually Chaim - Life), then you would probably just pick up his new name as "ben ploni Chaim". I think that I have seen this happen. Since I do not (yet) have sources, I am leaving this a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about the "Ploiny ben Patrick" thing...if the father is not Jewish, do you say "ben avrohom"?

Comment: @sabbahillel I guess I should say "Jew or Jewess" :-/ (although really it was my question that set the bad example)

Comment: @SAH, if the father's not Jewish, we do say b' Avraham/Sarah (depending on context of course)

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26301/naming-after-someone-with-added-names?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I found a reference that once the name has been changed, the children are to use the new name from that point on. They are called to the torah with the new name and do not have to undergo any procedure.

[The Halacha of Changing One’s Jewish Name](https://tools4saymyname.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/the-halacha-of-changing-ones-jewish-name/) Summary provided by Rabbi Levi Alter

> The Sefer Ta’amei HaMinhagim quotes from the Shaloh Kitzur 335, Inyanei
>   Sefer Torah that this name will be used when the person and person’s
>   children are called to the Torah. In the Shulchan Aruch Even HaEzer
>   Siman 129 Sif 18 the Ramo rules regarding a Get that the new name and
>   any nickname associated with it is to be mentioned first. The Pischei
>   Teshuvah Sif Katan 53, 54 and the Be’er Heitev Sif Katan 32 concur.